# Rewrite all links to index.php with multiple slashes

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i searched in internet solution to my problem but i can't find it. So i want to redirect (RewriteRule) all links to index.php like:
localhost, localhost/x, localhost/x-y, localhost/x-y/z

I readed about it and my .htaccess fle:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Where is problem? I have problem with my CSS file, it's located in includes/css/style.css. When link is like this: localhost or localhost/x everything is okay, but when i add more slashes file doesn't load.

HTML of this part:

```
<link href="./includes/css/basicstyle.css" type="text/CSS" rel="Stylesheet">
```

I know that this problem is easy for many people, but i tried do it for 2 days and i don't have any progres.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what wordpress is using...

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]  
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]  
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

maybe this would help?

```
RewriteRule ^(includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php|.*\.css|.*\.js)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

but i have to say, that i dont have many experience with mod rewrite, but hopefully it helps :)

Comment: Very thanks Mephiztopheles :) To your code working ineed to replace ./includes to /includes, but it's working. Thank you very much one more time :)

Comment: nice :) always happy to help